# Linux: Checking if a socket/pipe is broken without doing a read()/write()

Tags: linux, sockets, pipe

I have a simple piece of code that periodically writes data to a fd that's passed to it. The fd will most likely be a pipe or socket but could potentially be anything. I can detect when the socket/pipe is closed/broken whenever I write() to it, since I get an EPIPE error (I'm ignoring SIGPIPE). But I don't write to it all the time, and so might not detect a closed socket for a long time. I need to react to the closure asap. Is there a method of checking the fd without having to do a write()? I could then do this periodically if I'm not writing anything.

Comment: select, poll, and epoll will all tell you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure how to make this work with pipes. I've tried a select() call with my fd in the write and except fdsets, and the result of the call does not change when the pipe is broken (always return my fd in the write set). I've also tried poll() with all events set and again there's no difference.

Comment: Do not push your fd into the write fdsets. Only the except one.

Comment: Tried that, no luck with pipes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
struct pollfd pfd = {.fd = yourfd, .events = POLLERR};
if (poll(&pfd, 1, whatever) < 0) abort();
if (pfd.revents & POLLERR) printf("pipe is broken\n");
```

This does work for me. Note that sockets are not exactly pipes and thus show different behavior (-> use POLLRDHUP).

Comment: Aha! I had a typo and was checking events on the way out instead of revents. Many thanks, this worked great.

Comment: Great answer. I am too much accustom to select() call. I must definitively try to evolve on that point. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try with select and its errorfds parameter:

```
int **select**(int nfds, fd_set *restrict readfds,
      fd_set *restrict writefds, **fd_set *restrict errorfds**,
      struct timeval *restrict timeout);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried adding my fd to the exception set and couldn't get it to behave differently when the pipe was broken. (It might work fine with socket; I haven't tried yet since my current setup gives me a pipe)

Answer (score 2):

Nice answers, I like them... I also need to get out of the select habbit and into the (e)poll.

Here's some more traditional methods, if you need them:

```
/* check whether a file-descriptor is valid */
int fd_valid(int fd)
{   
    if (fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) == -1 && errno == EBADF) return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

This one attempts to duplicate the socket/fd.  It a lot simpler than in looks, I left a lot of debug in.

```
/* check a file descriptor */
int fd_check(int i) {
    int fd_dup = dup(i);
    if (fd_dup == -1) {
        strcpy(errst, strerror(errno));
        // EBADF  oldfd isnâ€™t an open file descriptor, or newfd is out of the allowed range for file descriptors.
        // EBUSY  (Linux only) This may be returned by dup2() during a race condition with open(2) and dup().
        // EINTR  The dup2() call was interrupted by a signal; see signal(7).
        // EMFILE The process already has the maximum number of file descriptors open and tried to open a new one.

        if (errno == EBADF) {
            return FALSE;
        }   

        return TRUE;
    }   
    close(fd_dup);
    return TRUE;
}
```