# C socket recv() error handling

Tags: c

I have a question about recv() function in socket (on linux Raspberri Pi)

Why does my program stops at:

```
if ((numbytes = recv(fd, odp, 100, 0)) == -1) {
    printf("\n error while test recv 1");
    perror("recv");
    reconnect = 1;
}
```

Yes, there is an error: "Resource remporarily unavaliable"

When i see:
`printf("\n error while test recv 1");`

i want to handle reconnect what is made later.
But i see on terminal window that my program stops on:

`error while test recv 1`

I've tried with:

`signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`

than with:

`signal(SIGPIPE, my_function);`

but it stops at either.

Some code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

while(1) {          

    if(reconnect){
        close(fd);
        fd = createSocket(argv[1]);
        reconnect=0;
    }

reconnect = connectionTest(fd);

}


int connectionTest(int *fd) {

  numbytes=send(fd, buf, 100,0);

  if ((numbytes = recv(fd, reply, 100, 0)) == -1) {
/* HERE IT STOPS */
    perror("recv");
    printf("\n error while test recv 1");

    reconnect = 1;

  }

    return reconnect;
}

int createSocket(char *server_addr){

 int sockfd;
 struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
 int rv;
 char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
 int set = 1;

signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

printf("connect to: %s", server_addr); 

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(server_addr, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }
        else printf("socketd created! \n");

    int set = 1;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, MSG_NOSIGNAL, (void *)&set, sizeof(int));

      if (setsockopt( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *)&set, sizeof(int)) < 0 )
      perror("setsockopt failed \n");

struct timeval timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = 4;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;


      if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0 ) 
      perror("setsockopt failed \n");

      if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0 ) 
      perror("setsockopt failed \n");

      printf("Try to connect \n");
      if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("client: connect");
      }
      else {
        printf("i have connection");
        break;
     }
   }

printf("next1");  

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

return  sockfd;
}
```

Comment: Post more code, especiall how reconnect variable is handled. And how socket is created and connected. Have you tried GDB?

Comment: can you try putting the `perror()` before the `printf`? Just in case the latter modifies the `errno` for any reason.

Comment: You are saying that the program quits with `broken pipe` even if you try to ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal?

Comment: Your program crashes because you don't handle the broken pipe signal correctly. You should give us the code on how you create the socket and how and when you ignore the signal.

Comment: I have an error "Resource temporarily unavaliable" than it stops. if i ignore SIGPIPE - i do not hande it -  just want to try reconnect - create new socket and connect - it works.

Comment: You should be able to ignore the `SIGPIPE` and handle the error using the return value of the `recv`. What system are you on ?

Comment: Please clarify your question: Show a complete sequence of code that shows the errors. Explain what the code sequence is supposed to do. Explain what errors you encounter instead. There was nothing in your original description about "Resource temporarily unavailable".

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: What do you mean by "my program stops"? Does your program actually exit? If so, what is the error on the screen when it does so? Or, does it just lock up in an infinite loop?

Comment: The SIGPIPE/EPIPE most likley dues to the call to send(). Compile the sources with all warnings on, mod it until no more warnings are given. Add error checking to all system calls. Do not return values which could represent a valid result to indicate an error.

Answer (score 1):

You program may stop at the `recv` because it receive the `SIGPIPE` signal.

If you already try ignoring this signal with `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)` note that you should do this before starting any thread otherwise one may be able to catch the signal before you ignore it.

---

Also note that you may be able to use `setsockopt` to configure your socket not to generate a SIGPIPE signal :

```
int optval = 1;
setsockopt(cs, SOL_SOCK, SO_NOSIGPIPE, (void *)&optval, sizeof(int))
```

This may not be available in your system.

---

Your system may also allow you to use the MSG_NOSIGNAL option in the recv to avoid the raise of the SIGPIPE signal :

```
recv(fd, odp, 100, MSG_NOSIGNAL ))
```

I think it works on Linux 2.2+

---

Once the signal is correctly ignored, your `recv` should return and you should be able to handle the error.

EDIT

Also you may have a XY problem here, **if you want to detect if the pipe is broken, you don't actually have to read or write to it**, you can use [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), also see : [Linux: Checking if a socket/pipe is broken without doing a read()/write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212243/linux-checking-if-a-socket-pipe-is-broken-without-doing-a-read-write).

Comment: I've tried recv(fd, odp, 100, MSG_NOSIGNAL ))                       and signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN); and it still stops on "Resource remporarily unavaliable" . ok - i will check poll

Comment: I wonder what system this happens on, as `read()` or `recv()` shall not raise `SIGPIPE` nor shall these calls set `errno` to `EPIPE` ...

Comment: @szymon hrapkowicz: "*Resource remporarily unavaliable*"  This smells like something completly different than a communication issue ...

Comment: i use raspberry pi with Raspbian “wheezy”  - here i use client socket like the code i posted. So what can i change/put into my code? :)

Comment: @szymonhrapkowicz note that you should update your post with any usefull information you give in comments.

Answer (score 1):

`read()` shall **not** return EPIPE.

If a `write()` is issued against a connection which had been `shutdown()` or even `close()`d by the other side the issueing process erros in any case.

A `SIGPIPE` is raised and if not handled nor is blocked the process will terminate. If `SIGPIPE` is handled or blocked `write()` shall return `-1` and sets `errno` to `EPIPE`.